# How to count multiple cell values individually and then assign to a list using linq

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

I have a table Products

```
Id, Name, Photo, Price,Total_Products
```

Now my requirement is the column Total_Products contain value based upon the products.

```
for example 
Id    Name              Photo                          Price    Total_Products
1     Samsung Galaxy    ~/Products/samsung-galaxy.jpg  15000    1
2     Apple IPhone      ~/Products/IPhone.jpg          20000    2
3     Nokia Lumia       ~/Products/Nokia-Lumia.jpg     10000    0
4     ...........................................................
5     ...........................................................
```

Here I just want to count the no of each product using Total_Products and I want to display Out of Stock message just above the image of Product. I am having the action method

```
public ActionResult Products()
    {                       
        return View(db.Products.ToList());
    }
```

The above code gives me all the particulars I want to count each product value if it exceeds greater than 1 then I want a msg just above the image saying Out of Stock [image]

Comment: show your view code as well how are you displaying

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad how to decrement the record value from for example the total no of products  is 1 then upon placing the order how should I  get the value and substract 1 from it. Plz comment if unclear

Comment: you will need to update in database on order checkout and then repopulate view

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're after, but you'd probably want something like:

```
@foreach (var product in Model) 
{
    <div class="product">
        @if (product.Total_Products < 1)
        {
            <div>Out of Stock</div>
        }
        <img src="@product.Photo"/>
        <div>@product.Name</div>
    </div>
}
```

**EDIT**

To decrement your total products when an order is submitted, you'd end up with something like this (heavily simplified):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Order(SubmitOrderModel model) 
{
    var product = db.Products.Single(p => p.Id = model.productId);

    // create your order record
    // ...

    // update inventory
    product.Total_Products -= 1;
    db.SubmitChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("OrderSuccess");
}
```

Comment: equal to zero can be checked though

Comment: how to decrement a total_products value to 1 when a order is placed

Comment: @User this would be done in your action method that handles form submission. Next time the page loads, it will reflect the current stock in the database. Or do you need everyone's page to update when someone else submits an order?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad it can, but inventory often goes negative - equal to zero won't pick this up.

Comment: @Sam and how about decrementing value for total_products when an item is purchased